# How do I silence my phone for ten minutes?

Tags: iphone

How do I temporarily enable do-not-disturb mode for 10 minutes?

If I turn on do not disturb, silent mode, or airplane mode then I tend to forget to turn it off. If so, I miss important work messages.

I use WeChat and suffer from flurries of activity. Somebody will start a chat room, pull you in, and then your phone will beep and shake constantly for about 10 minutes.

Comment: Presently, I just turn on airplane mode. And then I forget to turn it off and I get in trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Schedule DND on WeChat or iPhone. Can also mute a specific group on WeChat.

Otherwise ask Siri to "turn on do not disturb" and "set a timer for 10 minutes".